# Group and sum scores - any ideas on this one?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating 2 rows of data for each game as shown below.  I can then create the SQL code to generate the W,L, PF, PA and diff column as shown.  Does anyone know how to create the same data by entering just ONE game result?

Thanks.

```
id | game | team1     | team2     | score1 | score2 | gameset | diff
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1    | Reagan    | Jefferson | 43     | 48     | 0       | -5      
2  | 1    | Jefferson | Reagan    | 48     | 43     | 1       |  5
```

-

```
id | team       | win | loss | PF | PA | diff
-----------------------------------------------
1  | Jefferson  | 1   | 0    | 48 | 43 |  5
2  | Reagan     | 0   | 1    | 43 | 48 | -5
```

**SQL CODE:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, team1, Sum(diff) as tdiff,
               Sum(If(score1>score2,2,0)) + Sum(If(score1=score2,1,0)) +
                   Sum(If(score1+score2=0,-1,0)) AS Pts, 
               Sum(If(score1>score2,1,0)) AS Wins, 
               Sum(If(score1<score2,1,0)) AS Losses, 
               Sum(If(score1+score2=0,-1,0)) + Sum(If(score1=score2,1,0)) AS Ties,
               Sum(score2) AS Allowed, Sum(score1) AS Scored
          FROM database
      GROUP BY team1 ORDER BY Pts DESC, Allowed ASC, Scored DESC, team1 ASC';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*entering just ONE game result*"? Can you give an example of desired output?

Comment: @ZaneBien presumably the second table is the desired result.

Comment: I don't think so. The OP says: `"I can then create the SQL code to generate the W,L, PF, PA and diff column as shown."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the UNION of two queries.  However, it is not clear what the `id` column should be in the result, so I've left it out.  Isn't it more usual to have 2 points for a win, 1 for a draw and 0 for a loss?  Your formula seems to give no points for a score-less draw.  The UNION designates two scores, the 'team score' or `t_score`, and the 'opponents score' or `o_score`.  It effectively creates two rows for each row in the `database` table (which would be more conventionally named something like `game_results` — 'database' should be reserved for a collection of tables, not for individual tables).

```
SELECT team, SUM(diff) AS tdiff,
       SUM(IF(t_score > o_score, 2, 0)) +
           SUM(IF(t_score = o_score, 1, 0)) +
           SUM(IF(t_score + o_score =0, -1, 0)) AS Pts, 
       SUM(IF(t_score > o_score, 1, 0)) AS Wins, 
       SUM(IF(t_score < o_score, 1, 0)) AS Losses, 
       SUM(IF(t_score + o_score = 0, -1, 0)) +
           SUM(IF(t_score = o_score, 1, 0)) AS Ties,
       SUM(o_score) AS Allowed,
       SUM(t_score) AS Scored
  FROM (SELECT team1 AS team, game, 'H' AS home_away,
               score1 AS t_score, score2 AS o_score
          FROM database
        UNION ALL
        SELECT team2 AS team, game, 'A' AS home_away,
               score2 AS t_score, score1 AS o_score
          FROM database
       ) AS R 
  GROUP BY team ORDER BY Pts DESC, Allowed ASC, Scored DESC, team ASC;
```

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed Jonathan!  Got me on the right track and got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

This was EXACTLY what I needed Jonathan!  Got me on the right track and got it to work!  Updated code is below

SELECT team, SUM(t_score-o_score) as tdiff,
                                SUM(IF(t_score > o_score, 2, 0)) +
                                SUM(IF(t_score = o_score, 1, 0)) +
                                SUM(IF(t_score + o_score =0, -1, 0)) AS Pts, 
                                SUM(IF(t_score > o_score, 1, 0)) AS Wins, 
                                       SUM(IF(t_score < o_score, 1, 0)) AS Losses, 
                                       SUM(IF(t_score + o_score = 0, -1, 0)) +
                                           SUM(IF(t_score = o_score, 1, 0)) AS Ties,
                                       SUM(o_score) AS Allowed,
                                       SUM(t_score) AS Scored
                  FROM (SELECT id, diff, team1 AS team, game, 'H' AS home_away,
                                               score1 AS t_score, score2 AS o_score
                          FROM mn_alldistrictgames
                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT id, diff, team2 AS team, game, 'A' AS home_away,
                                               score2 AS t_score, score1 AS o_score
                          FROM mn_alldistrictgames
                       ) AS R 
  GROUP BY team ORDER BY Pts DESC, Allowed ASC, Scored DESC, team ASC

Comment: Don't forget to mark his helpful answer as correct! That gives him prestige points, and a record of accepting good answers will encourage people to answer any future questions you post.